# How do I assign a char* to a char array?

Tags: c++, char

Compiler tell me "incompatibles type in assignments of char* to char[32]"
this is my code:

```
char* generalOperations[2]={"Off","On"};

 void test(){
   char value[32];
    switch(swapVariable){
     case 0:
      value=generalOperations[0]; //<==Error HERE!
     break;
    }

 }
```

[Solved]:

```
  strcpy(value,generalOperations[0]);
```

Comment: Don’t use `char*` or `char[]`. Use `std::string` or, in some cases, `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: Is this is really C++? Looks like C.

Comment: @Gabriel I see how this looks like C, but it was clearly tagged C++.

Comment: @Luchian: Your right, shouldn't have retagged it.

Comment: `-1` from me for the "[Solved]" appendix. This is a buffer overflow waiting to happen in your code. If you know so little about C++, you should definitely follow the most-upvoted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Use `std::string` instead of `char*` and `std::array<T, N>` instead of `T[N]`. Both are type safe (as opposed to `memcpy`), both are in modern C++ style and both are directly assignable using the assignment operator.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

std::array<std::string, 2> generalOperations{"Off", "On"};

void test() {
    std::string value;
    switch(swapVariable) {
        case 0: value = generalOperations[0]; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign arrays. You can either change the type of `value` to a `char*` or copy the content of `generalOptions[0]` into `value`. If you are going to copy the content, then you need to ensure that `value` has enough space to hold the content of the element in `generalOperations`.

Modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour, by changing the type to `const char*` the compiler can detect any attempt to modify one of the entries in `generalOperations` instead of experiencing odd behaviour at runtime:

```
const char* generalOperations [2]={"Off","On"};

const char* value;
```

Note you don't have to specify the number of elements in the array if you are initialising it:

```
const char* generalOperations [] = {"Off","On"};
```

Or, if this really is C++ you can make `value` a `std::string` instead and just assign to it which will copy the `generalOperations` element.

---

As C++ appears to really be the language and C++11 features are permitted instead of using a `switch` you could create a `std::map` that associates the `int` values with the `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

const std::map<int, std::string> generalOperations{ {17, "Off"},
                                                    {29, "On" } };
int main()
{
    auto e = generalOperations.find(17);
    if (e != generalOperations.end())
    {
        // Do something with e->second.
        std::cout << e->second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/rvFxH.

Comment: I would also recommend making char* generalOperations a const char*. Treating char* as a string literal can cause warnings on most compilers.

Comment: @DeadMG, its mentioned in the answer. Additionally, I think the question is mistagged as there is nothing specific to C++ whatsoever.

Comment: You mean like people using C++ as C with Classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>

...
strcpy(value, generalOptions[0]);
```

You cannot assign arrays in C/C++. There are functions do to that for you. If your char array represents a C style string (i.e. a null terminated sequence of characters), then there are more specialist functions for that as well. `strcpy` is one of those functions.

Comment: Wow, I'm not going to dignify that comment with an answer.

Comment: @john: Instead, you could dignify it with picking up [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/140719) and learn something.

Comment: @ubi I know C++, I've read the first 6 books on that list you helpfully provided (excluding the C++ 11 ones). I tailor my answers to what I think will be helpful to the OP, I don't automatically answer with the highest powered C++ I can manage. That's not going to help many of the newbies who post here. I'll grant that the above isn't my best ever answer since I should have seen that the OPs attempt to copy arrays was a good oppotunity to introduce std::string precisely because it can be copied in the way the OP was trying with arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Your assignment is wrong, since you cannot assign a char * to char array instead of using this assignment you can use strcpy().